# Is there any way to remove specific characters from a filename in Windows, using a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename, filenames

I would like to rename every file in a directory that contains '[' or ']' characters by removing any instance of those two characters from those filenames.

I have yet to determine any way to read filenames character-by-character with a batch file.

Thanks!

Comment: Did one of the answers below solve your issue?

Comment: Yes, your answer solved it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to read the filename character by character. In batch you can simply replace all occurrences of a substring `subs` with another substring `repl` in the value of a variable `%var%` with `%var:subs=repl%`. As removing is the same as replacing with an empty string (in batch at least), `%var:h=%` will remove all `h`s from the value of the `var` variable. So all you need is to store the filename in a variable and you can have the new filename without `[` and/or `]`.
To iterate over all files in a directory you'll just need a [`FOR`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) loop.

So you can iterate over all files in the current directory and rename the ones with `[` or `]` in their name (or both) with the following script (see edit for version which also handles names with exclamation marks):

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR %%G IN (*) DO (
    set "filename=%%~G"
    set "filename=!filename:[=!"
    set "filename=!filename:]=!"
    REM Rename only if there is a difference between new filename and old filename in %%G
    IF NOT "!filename!" == "%%~G" ren "%%~G" "!filename!"
)
EndLocal
exit /b 0
```

Because the `filename` variable is set inside the `FOR` block and we want to read it inside the same block, we need [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

**EDIT**: As @dbenham said in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42293834/is-there-any-way-to-remove-specific-characters-from-a-filename-in-windows-using/42294386?noredirect=1#comment71784839_42294386), **delayed expansion can cause problems when you have filenames containing exclamation marks `!`** (`%%~G` will then contain a `!` which normally announces a variable being expanded with delayed expansion). To solve that problem, @dbenham proposed a nice solution: enable delayed expansion only when we're about to use it i.e. inside the `FOR` block, just before using the `filename` variable. The `!` won't poisin the value of a variable expanded with delayed expansion so `!filename!` can be used without a `!` being misinterpreted in its value. This also means we'll have to move `EndLocal` to after we're done using delayed expansion in the `FOR` block (i.e. at the end of the block) and avoid the use of `%%~G` in the `ren` command. The latter can be done by using a variable to hold the original name (also before enabling delayed expansion) and use delayed expansion to retrieve the original name. That variable can then actually be used to construct the new filename.

```
@echo off

FOR %%G IN (*) DO (
    REM Set filename without delayed expansion, no misinterpreted '!' possible
    set "old_filename=%%~G"
    REM before using old_filename, enable delayed expansion
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "new_filename=!old_filename:[=!"
    set "new_filename=!new_filename:]=!"
    REM Rename only if there is a difference between new filename and old filename in %%G
    ren "!old_filename!" "!new_filename!"
    REM No more delayed expansion needed in block now
    EndLocal
)

exit /b 0
```

Also, [@KlitosKyriacou](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42293834/is-there-any-way-to-remove-specific-characters-from-a-filename-in-windows-using/42294386#comment71746171_42294386) pointed out the `IF` was actually unnecessary: renaming a file with its original filename causes no harm. I've left it out in my 2nd version (the edit-version).

Comment: It's benign to rename a file to itself, so the check isn't strictly necessary (though it won't hurt to make it).

Comment: This will fail if a file name contains `!` because delayed expansion will corrupt value of `%%~G`. Easily fixed by moving `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` to after initial assignment of `filename`, and `endlocal` to bottom of `DO` block, effectively toggling delayed expansion on and off within the loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing that out @dbenham. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou thanks also for pointing that out. I've incorporated that in my edit as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you are able to use **PowerShell** and have one folder where all files are located you can run a command like

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "[","" }
```

and

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "]","" }
```

to get rid of the characters.

Comment: I think the OP requested a batch-script. Maybe you should mention this is not batch

Answer (score 2):

You could use [JREN.BAT - a regular expression renaming command line utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081). JREN.BAT is pure script (hybrid batch/JScript) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward - no 3rd party exe required.

Using alternation, which requires escape of `[`

```
jren "\[|]" ""
```

or a character set, with escaped `]`

```
jren "[[\]]" ""
```

or a character set, with `]` as first member of set

```
jren "[][]" ""
```

Any of the above syntaxes can easily be extended to strip additional characters.

You must use `call jren` if you put the command within a batch script.

Regardless of what technique you use to solve this, the operation may fail if the renamed value conflicts with an already existing file name.